# Intuition behind steps in formulating Finite Element Method

Tags: partial-differential-equations, finite-element-method, galerkin-methods

Let's consider the classic elastostatics case where the strong form of the PDE is:

$\sigma _{ij,j}+b_i =0$ on V

By multiplying through by weighting functions and integrating we can create an equivalent weak form of the problem:

$ \int (\sigma ^u_{ij,j}+b_i)\lambda _i  dV $

My question is what is the intuition behind this weak formulation? What is the point of multiplying through by these weighting functions, $\lambda_i$?
And why choose our weighting functions to be from the same basis of our solution space?

My guess is these weighting functions act as a "correction factor," but i'm a little confused on their purpose. Is there a more mathematical way of explaining this formulation?

Comment: It is called the [Weak Formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_formulation) of the original problem.

Comment: Looks like a scalar product, $\langle Lu. \lambda\rangle = 0$ so there might be a connection to the theory of distributions.

Comment: Test functions serve as the approximation function space usually in the symmetric problems in finite element. This means the components of $\sigma$ are approximated in terms of linear combination of different $\lambda$'s.

Comment: The finite element method is a special case of Galerkin methods.  Integration by parts is often involved in getting to a weak formulation/bilinear form that yields an approximation to solutions for boundary conditions.  There is a bunch of literature.

Comment: @hardmath right, but my question is not what this weak form is or how to reduce the order using integration by parts, it is WHY we bother to use these weighting functions, or "test functions" as ShuHao Cao said.

Comment: Big picture is that we get a discrete (finitely many unknowns) problem whose solution approximates the continuous problem (electrostatics, etc.) we started with.   The properties of a useful bilinear form in this regard are easier to state in a positive definite symmetric case, so one often tries for that first.

Comment: @hardmath could you relate this weak formulation to a projection onto  a subspace of weighting functions? That's what this inner product is doing, right? I think I may be able to understand this better if we talk about this in terms of orthogonality and projections

Comment: If you've looked at the Wikipedia article on electrostatics, you will have seen that in terms of *electric potential* $\phi$, the governing PDE is Poisson''s equation.  A weak formulation of this does give a bilinear form that can be viewed as an inner product.

Comment: @hardmath I know what I am looking at, my question is not "what am I seeing" it is *why*! I am trying to build intuition behind these equations by understanding what exactly is going on when we:
1) multiply by weighting functions
2) choose our weighting functions from the same space as our solution
3) A physical interpretation of this weak form - in terms of projections/orthogonality since we have what looks like an inner product

Answer (score 0):

Being absolutely ignorant when it comes to elastostatics, I can only say something about **intuition** behind finite element methods in the context of fluid flow and heat transfer. My main conclusion is this: *an intuition of the sort as mentioned by the OP is not quite there*.
To be honest, I have seldomly found the Galerkin method useful, let it be insightful. When it comes to for example convection-diffusion problems it is indeed weak in the true sense of the word, giving the wrong scheme (central differences instead of upwind differences) for the convective terms.
Therefore I think it's advantageous to somehow relax the predominance of the weak formulation.
One of the best alternatives for my own applications has been the *resistor network* paradigm. See:

- [**Resistor Networks**](http://westy31.home.xs4all.nl/Electric.html#Irregular)
  in [**2-D**](http://www.alternatievewiskunde.nl/jaar2004/purified.pdf)
  and [**3-D**](http://www.alternatievewiskunde.nl/sunall/belgisch.pdf).